# Not Recognizing Loop Variable in Python

Tags: python, variables

I am trying to delete 38 lines of text after coming across a certain phrase in a .txt file in Python, while still printing the rest of the text.

The code I currently have is

```
with open('text_file.txt','r') as f:
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if "certain_phrase" in line:
        for num in range(38):
            del line
    else:
        print(line,end='')
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\<location of file>\python_program.py", line 6, in <module>
    del line
NameError: name 'line' is not defined
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or clues as to why it does not recognize "line" once I've put it inside the for loop below? Additionally, is there a better way to execute this kind of program?

Comment: this code will not do what you want it to do even if there was no error

Comment: it does not know the variable `line` at the second iteration of your `for num in ...` loop because you just deleted it during previous iteration and did not redefine it in between

Comment: First advice: no need for line 2 when reading a file (it's a waste of memory since you store the entire file in memory instead of reading it line by line) => `for line in f`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to remove from the list, you cannot  `del` the line, the easiest way is to write to a temp file and copy after if you want to modify the file, if you just want to print ignoring the 38 line replace write with print:

```
 with open('in.txt','r') as f,open('temp.txt','w') as temp:
    for line in f:
        if "phrase" in line:
            for i in range(38):
                next(f) # skip 38 lines
        else:
            temp.write(line)
```

Then use shutil to move the file:

```
import shutil

shutil.move("temp.txt","in.txt")
```

You can also use a  [NamedTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile):

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

with open('file.txt','r') as f, NamedTemporaryFile(dir=".",delete=False) as  temp:
    for line in f:
        if "phrase" in line:
            for i in range(38):
                next(f)
        else:
            temp.write(line)

import shutil
shutil.move(temp.name,"file.txt")
```

The only potential problem I see is if the phrase is in one of the 38 ignored lines and you should also remove the next 38 lines from there.

```
To ignore until a second phrase, keep looping in the inner loop until you find the second phrase then break:

with open('in.txt','r') as f, NamedTemporaryFile(dir=".", delete=False) as temp:
    for line in f:
        if "phrase" in line:
            for _line in f:
                if "phrase2" in _line:
                    break
        else:
            temp.write(line)
```

Comment: This works exceptionally well! Thank you so much! Very useful to know!

Comment: couldn't you use a while loop and reset the counter if the phrase is within the 38 ignored lines?

Comment: I know that "there should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it," but I think both methods are equally good.

Comment: @cody yes do the check in the inner loop and break if you find the second phrase looping over f instead of using range. I will edit when i get back on my comp

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to delete lines from a file, write a new file based on the old one. The following uses `__next__()` to skip over `line`s yielded by the generator.

```
with open('text_file.txt','r') as f, open('text_file_mod.txt', 'w') as w:
    for line in f:
        w.write(line)
        if "certain_phrase" in line:
            for num in range(38): # skip 38 lines
                next(f)
```

If you're doing this from the interactive interpreter, you can prevent it from spitting out returned values by saving the results of `next(f)` and `w.write(line)` to variables.

Answer (score 0):

`del line` actually deletes the variable `line`, meaning that when you try to do that a second time, it doesn't work, because `line` isn't defined anymore. You can loop over indices to find the line, break, then delete the next 38 lines:

```
with open('text_file.txt','r') as f:
lines = f.readlines()
for i in range(len(lines)):
    if "certain_phrase" in lines[i]:
        break
    else:
        print(line,end='')
for num in range(38):
    del lines[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('temp.txt','r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        print(line,end="") #you want to print the phrase, right?
        if "certain_phrase" in line:
            for _ in range(38):
                next(line)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this does not do what the asker wanted... this deletes the first 38 lines that contains "certain_phrase" as opposed to reading until it finds "certain_phrase" in a line and then deleting (or really skipping) the next 38 lines