# python read file and skip n lines and read again and skip

Tags: python

I am new to python. I need to read the first 11 lines then skip next 9 lines and read two, skip next 9 lines and read two until the end of the file.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Good for you. What have you tried? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Please post your attempt, sample input, expected output, actual output, and the full text of any tracebacks or errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not Recognizing Loop Variable in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29434734/not-recognizing-loop-variable-in-python)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 How is this a duplicate of that question?

Comment: Because that question is asking how to skip lines while reading through a file, just like this one. That question's title is simply asking the wrong question ("why does X not work" instead of "I'm trying to do Y and can't figure out how, but I've tried X").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=islice#itertools.islice) in the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=islice) module to read "slices" of lines from the file via a [generator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-generator) function:

```
import itertools

def lines_of_interest(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as inf:
        for line in itertools.islice(inf, 11):  # yield the first 11 lines
            yield line
        while True:
            # out of next 11 lines, skip 9 and keep last 2
            lines = list(itertools.islice(inf, 9, 11))
            for line in lines:
                yield line
            if not lines:  # end-of-file?
                break
```

Usage example:

```
# create a test file
with open('data.dat', 'w') as outf:
    for i in xrange(1, 110):
        outf.write('line #%d\n' % i)

for line in lines_of_interest('data.dat'):
    # process line...
    print line,
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the general idea:
1. read your lines from the file into a list using readlines()
2. use a for loop to loop over the indices of the lines
3. use if statements within the loop to skip the appropriate lines.

MattDMo is correct.  It'd help if you'd show us your attempt.